# In Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Whatever happened to the Dursleys?

Tags: harry-potter

I mean, Harry said that Voldemort would try to find the Dursleys. But now he's dead. So what happened to them?

Comment: Hi Luna, welcome to Stack Exchange! I've closed your question as a duplicate since it's already been asked before here, but don't take this as discouragement - it's a good question and I also upvoted it. I hope you stick around, take our [tour], and maybe ask and answer some more questions :-)